# Preserve CKEditor formatting when clearing editor and typing new content

Tags: ckeditor

If I select all CKEditor text (or select and delete all text), then start typing new text into the empty editor, CKEditor seems to do a good job of recovering prior formatting and applying it to the newly typed text. However, there are situations where this feature doesn't work as well (e.g. IE).

We have a customer that is requiring that formatting NEVER be lost when a customer selects or deletes all text from the editor and starts typing new text, so I need to make this behavior work more reliably than is currently implemented natively in CKEditor.

Any recommendations on the best approach to detect this scenario and take control of the formatting that is applied to new text in an empty editor?

Comment: Have you considered simply formatting the `body` tag for the editor accordingly? Or do you need to apply whatever prior formatting there was, not just the default?

Comment: @Pekka 웃 My requirement is to restore user's most recent formatting.

Comment: That might be very difficult. I guess you could catch the selected area and exclude the topmost `div` or `p` element from the selection... but then the formatting info may just as well be in some *other* element, removed from the top a couple of steps.

Comment: I would say that what you're describing as a feature, it's instead a bug. When a user selects all and clears the content, I would expect that everything is cleared: text and format.